# why RE(random effects) model is better than FE model when it comes to degrees of freedom?

Tags: panel-data

To get rid of unobserved heterogeneity, all individual-specific variables which are time-constant are removed by FE model. So to my knowledge, whether we need to include lots of dummies to include FE variables, it doesn't matter because we are gonna subtract all those variables while getting FE estimator.

To put it briefly, I don't get the degrees of freedom issue when it comes to pros and cons of RE and FE models respectively.

What are your thoughts?(I'm just a beginner)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "subtract all those variables"?  That is an unusual description of a fixed effects regression.